# Count days within dateranges while excluding overlapping days

Tags: mysql, date, count, overlapping

I'm looking for the number of days within several dateranges. I used the datediff function to sum the days, but now I want to exclude overlapping days. So from the oldest date untill curdate I would like to have the number of days within the dateranges and every day only counted once if it is in an overlapping range.

My table looks like this:

```
Person_id |      Start_date      | End_date              | Count
 83244       2014-09-01 00:00:00    2014-09-06 00:00:00    5
 83244       2014-09-08 00:00:00    2015-09-07 00:00:00    364
 83244       2015-01-15 00:00:00    2015-02-01 00:00:00    17
```

If I sum this I would get 382, but the answer I'm looking for is 369. Since the last row is completely overlapping the second row.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Hmm, seems doable at first, but what is the rule if periods overlap only partially? Like if the third period was until 2015-10-31? -- Ah, got it now, `count` actually gives the number of days in that range and is not an independent data column.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes, Column Count is a count of the number of days in de daterange. Tried to make it easier to explain my question. If ranges overlap partially it should count only the days of the part that is not overlapping

Comment: Working with a MySQL database

Comment: The end dates themselves do not count as part of the periods, i.e. they are the first day after the period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have padded out your example with a second `Person_id` and shortened the column names a bit to make the code a little shorter:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(`pid` int, `sd` datetime, `ed` datetime);
INSERT INTO tbl (`pid`, `sd`, `ed`)
VALUES
    (83244, '2014-09-01', '2014-09-06'),
    (83244, '2014-09-08', '2015-09-07'),
    (83243, '2014-08-08', '2015-08-15'),
    (83243, '2014-08-11', '2015-09-03'),
    (83244, '2015-01-15', '2015-02-01');
```

So, working on the above data you could apply the following query:

```
SELECT pid,sd,ed,CASE WHEN @id!=pid THEN @id:=pid+0*(@ed:=Date('1970-1-1')) END id, 
       CASE WHEN sd<@ed THEN CASE WHEN ed>@ed THEN datediff(ed,@ed) ELSE 0 END 
                        ELSE datediff(ed,sd) END days,
       @ed:=CASE WHEN ed>@ed THEN ed ELSE @ed END enddt
FROM tbl,( select @id:=0 ) const
ORDER BY pid,sd
```

Contrary to other RDBMS MySql has a certain "procedural feel" to it when it comes to `select` statements. You can actually use variables (`@id` and `@ed`) in them that will change their state over time (in this context the `order by` clause at the end is extremely important).

The basic idea behind this query is: start with a certain `pid` and list the intervals in the order of increasing start dates (`sd`). Always remember the maximum value of the end date (`ed`) in variable `@ed`. Now, with each new interval, check whether there is an overlap with the previous interval, i. e. check whether the current start date `sd` is smaller than the previous (maximum) end date (`@ed`) and calculate the interval `days` accordingly.

The first `case` clause is necessary to reset the variables `@id` and `@ed` whenever the current `pid` changes.

Subquery `const` just sets the variable `@id` in the beginning.

The query yields the following result:

```
  pid   sd                  ed                  id     days enddt
83243   2014-08-08 00:00:00 2015-08-15 00:00:00 83243   372 2015-08-15 00:00:00
83243   2014-08-11 00:00:00 2015-09-03 00:00:00          19 2015-09-03 00:00:00
83244   2014-09-01 00:00:00 2014-09-06 00:00:00 83244     5 2014-09-06 00:00:00
83244   2014-09-08 00:00:00 2015-09-07 00:00:00         364 2015-09-07 00:00:00
83244   2015-01-15 00:00:00 2015-02-01 00:00:00           0 2015-09-07 00:00:00
```

See here for a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7638/2).

If you are just interested in the total sums you can of course wrap the whole query in another `group`ing one like this:

```
SELECT pid,sum(days) FROM (
 SELECT pid,sd,ed,CASE WHEN @id!=pid THEN @id:=pid+0*(@ed:=Date('1970-1-1')) END id, 
        CASE WHEN sd<@ed THEN CASE WHEN ed>@ed THEN datediff(ed,@ed) ELSE 0 END 
                         ELSE datediff(ed,sd) END days,
        @ed:=CASE WHEN ed>@ed THEN ed ELSE @ed END enddt
 FROM tbl,( select @id:=0 ) const
 ORDER BY pid,sd
) t GROUP BY pid ORDER BY pid
```

which will then get you

```
pid     sum(days)
83243   391
83244   369
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try this query.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL will return the sum of days not counting the overlaps double:

```
select    person_id, sum(days)
from      (
    select    t1.person_id,
              t1.start_date,
              t1.end_date,
              case when t1.end_date > coalesce(greatest(max(t2.end_date), t1.start_date), t1.start_date) 
                   then datediff(t1.end_date, coalesce(greatest(max(t2.end_date), t1.start_date), t1.start_date))
                   else 0
              end  days
    from      t  t1
    left join t  t2 on t1.person_id = t2.person_id
                   and (t2.start_date < t1.start_date
                    or t2.start_date = t1.start_date and t2.end_date < t1.end_date)
    group by  t1.person_id,
              t1.start_date,
              t1.end_date
    ) detail
group by person_id
```

It is required that the periods are unique for a given person, so that no two periods have both the same *start_date* as *end_date*.

This [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a8a1/3) returns 369 for the sample data and person.

#### Alternative

You could create a sequence table (which is useful for many purposes) and then count unique days with that.

So as a one-shot operation you would extend your database model with an additional table that just contains natural numbers (0, 1, 2 ... ):

```
create table sequence (
  num int,
  primary key (num)
);

// Populate the above table with as many numbers as needed:
insert into sequence values(0);
insert into sequence select num+   1 from sequence; --    2 records
insert into sequence select num+   2 from sequence; --    4 records
insert into sequence select num+   4 from sequence; --    8 records
insert into sequence select num+   8 from sequence; --   16 records
insert into sequence select num+  16 from sequence; --   32 records
insert into sequence select num+  32 from sequence; --   64 records
insert into sequence select num+  64 from sequence; --  128 records
insert into sequence select num+ 128 from sequence; --  256 records
insert into sequence select num+ 256 from sequence; --  512 records
insert into sequence select num+ 512 from sequence; -- 1024 records
insert into sequence select num+1024 from sequence; -- 2048 records
insert into sequence select num+2048 from sequence; -- 4096 records
```

You can continue to insert records like that, but for the current task this is more than enough.

Now to the actual solution:

```
select     person_id, count(distinct num), count(num) 
from       sequence
cross join (select min(start_date) min_date,
                   max(end_date)   max_date
            from t) stats
inner join t
        on date_add(min_date, interval (num*24+12) hour)
           between start_date and end_date
where      num < datediff(max_date, min_date)
group by   person_id
```

This query uses the unique numbers for getting days starting from the earliest start date and includes such dates when they are in a period. Then it counts the unique dates that fulfil that condition.

The `where` clause is optional, but will speed up the query.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4c5e9/10). It produces this result:

```
| Person_id | count(distinct num) | count(num) |
|-----------|---------------------|------------|
|     83244 |                 369 |        386 |
```

Comment: When applying your first solution to my extended sample data (see above) it only returns a single result for one `person_id`. The "Alternative" solution works perfectly though and has the advantage of beeing applicable in any RDBMS almost unchanged (`DATEDIFF` and `date_add` might need some attention)!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @cars10, I had forgotten to add the `group by person_id` at the end. Is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Gonna try it!